# Django cached_property is not being cached

Tags: django, caching

I have the following in my models:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    person = models.ForeignKey(People, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @cached_property
    def tags(self):
        return Tag.objects.filter(person=self, type="A")
```

I would expect that when I do this:

```
person = People.objects.get(pk=1)
tags = person.tags
```

That this would result in 1 db query - only getting the person from the database. However, it continuously results in 2 queries - the tags table is being consistently queried even though this is supposedly cached. What can cause this? Am I not using the cached_property right?

The models are simplified to illustrate this case.

Comment: Could you please provide the exact code? In the code you give, `person.tags` is called only once, so it's hard to guess what could be wrong.

Answer (score 4):

You decorated `tags()` methods returns a *queryset* that is not evaluated yet. (Read more about when a queryset is evaluated in [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated)). To cache the results of the query you have to force the queryset first to evaluate to a list of objects:

```
class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @cached_property
    def tags(self):
        return list(Tag.objects.filter(person=self, type="A"))
```

Comment: I think this shouldn't be necessary to evaluate the queryset as a list. The tags() method should return a reference to the queryset, and when it is evaluated for the first time, it should set the `_result_cache` attribute. Subsequent calls to `person.tags` should return the same reference, with `_result_cache` already set.

Comment: @AntoinePinsard I was assuming the same first, but I tried it and it works for me as posted in the answer! Didn't have any time to dig deeper  why the `_result_cache` doesn't prevent an additional query (my only suspicion would probably be thast the queryset gets cloned before being evaluated, but as I said couldnt find the time to look into it)!

Comment: That's interesting and quite surprising. I made some tests and I believe you might have printed the queryset in the console for your tests. It seems that indeed, `_result_cache` is not set when using the `__str__()` method. My guess is that this is a convenience for console usage. However, once you explicitely iterate over the queryset, `_result_cache` is set, whether it comes from a cached property or not. https://gist.github.com/apinsard/9aafbcc3c4bb24d4732c6ed0f6c9bc36

Comment: Mhh yes you are probably right... Could also be a cause of the problem mentioned in the question that `__repr__()` when priting doesnt fill the result cache...

Comment: That could be, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to figure out what is wrong without seeing the code that actually calls the cached property multiple times. However, the way you describe your issue, `cached_property` seems to be the right approach and should work.

My guess is that there might be some misunderstanding about how it works. An example use case for a cached property would be:

```
person = People.objects.get(pk=1)  # <- Query on People executed
text_tags = ', '.join(person.tags)  # <- Query on Tags executed
html_tags = format_html_join(
    '\n',
    '<span class="tag tag-{}">{}</span>',
    ((t.type, t.name) for t in person.tags),  # <- tags loaded from cache, no query executed
)
```

However, if you do something like this:

```
for person in People.objects.all(): # <- Query on People executed
    text_tags = ', '.join(person.tags)  # <- Query on Tags executed FOR EACH ITERATION
    html_tags = format_html_join(
        '\n',
        '<span class="tag tag-{}">{}</span>',
        ((t.type, t.name) for t in person.tags),  # <- tags loaded from cache, no query executed
    )
```

The first call to `person.tags` of each iteration of the for loop executes a query. This is because the result of the property `tags` is cached **per instance**.

If you want to cache all the tags you need in advance when iterating over people objects, there are several approaches depending on your use case.

---

**The manual approach**

```
from itertools import groupby

all_tags = Tags.objects.filter(type="A").order_by('person_id')
# order_by() is important because we will use person_id as key to group the results using itertools.groupby()

# Create a dictionary matching a person to its list of tags using a single SQL query
people_tags = {
    person_id: list(tags)
    for person_id, tags in groupby(all_tags, lambda t: t.person_id)
}

for person in People.objects.all():
    # Try to find the person's tags in the dictionary, otherwise, set tags to an empty list
    tags = people_tags.get(person.id, [])
```

---

**The single query with aggregations approach**

For this approach, you will need to make sure your foreign key has a [related name](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name), to be able to make ["reverse" queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward):

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=1)
    person = models.ForeignKey(
        People,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='tags',
    )
```

Specifying `related_name` is not strictly required as Django gives a default related name but I can't ever remember how this name is built so I always give it explicitely.

**Don't forget to remove the `tags()` method as the name would clash with the related name "tags".**

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.postgres.aggregates import ArrayAgg


persons = (
    People.objects.all()
    .annotate(tags_names=ArrayAgg('tags__name', filter=Q(tags__type='A')))
)
for person in persons:
    tags = person.tags_names
```

Note that with this approach, `person.tags_names` will be a list of tag names as strings, not a list of Tag objects. There are some tricky ways to retrieve Tag objects, or at least more than a single field, using annotate() but I think this is beyond the scope of this question.

Also note that this will only work with PostgreSQL.

---

**Django's built-in way: prefetch_related()**

Django ships with a [prefetch_related()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) method on QuerySet objects. It is especially designed as a shortcut to the manual approach. This approach requires the use of the foreign key's `related_name` mentioned above.

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch

persons = (
    People.objects.all()
    .prefetch_related(
        Prefetch('tags', queryset=Tag.objects.filter(type='A'))
    )
)
for person in persons:
    tags = person.tags
```

Note that if you don't need to filter the tags by type, you can simply do `People.objects.prefetch_related('tags')`.